# where I can find all the order numbers from the Database table?

Tags: database

where I can find all the order numbers from which Database table? I did some research, but I don't see sales_flat_order in my database. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For magento 1.9** you can find order number in table `sales_flat_order` column name is `increment_id`

**for magento 2** you cand find order number in table `sales_order` column name is `increment_id`

Hope you find what you are looking for

Comment: thanks!! I overlook this column into this table